# How to retrieve the last row of a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How to retrieve the last row of a **table which doesn't has any unique id** like

```
select * from sample where id=(select max(id) from sample)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'last'? Most recently INSERTed?

Comment: Yes... I need to calculate next orderno from the previously inserted orderno.

Comment: there is no guaranteed way of doing this, even the top 1 * order by whatever DESC won't get the last row inserted, just the last row in the table order (the clustered index).  Your best bet at a minimum is a timestamp field to gauge the last inserted...

Comment: @tekiegreg: Incorrect. It would give the last one according to "whatever" descending. It would only give the last row from the clustered index if "whatever" is the clustered index sorted ASCending.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select TOP 1 * from sample order by whatever DESC
```

There must be some sort (ORDER BY) criteria to define the last row, otherwise your request makes no sense. For example, the last row based on `AddedDateTime` column in the `product` table

```
select TOP 1 * from product order by AddedDateTime DESC
```